# Getting RSSI cellular list on Android

Tags: android, rssi, signal-strength, cellid, phone-state-listener

How to get a list of RSSI for the cellular network connected to and the other cellular networks in range in android ? I have an idea that the phonestatelister has to be created and the signal strength changes have to be monitored.

Answer (score 0):

You can only check RSSI of your neighbours only in 2G network by code from this post:
[cellID and LAC / PSC for 3G neighboring cells in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701777/cellid-and-lac-psc-for-3g-neighboring-cells-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you imply that getting RSSI of 3G neighbors is not possible ?

Comment: Yes exactly is. I checked it on some Samsung phones.