# Query neighboring cells' cell-ids in android for 4G

Tags: android, telephony

I am interested in using mobile phones for conducting network field tests - i.e. collecting information about signal strength as well as other related values for a mobile network, in particular for 4G-LTE-networks.

There are a couple of applications already out there which can do this, e.g. GNet-Track (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyokovsolutions.gnettracklite)

These apps are using the `TelephonyManager`'s `getAllCellInfo()` to retrieve information for the serving cell (the cell to which the mobile is connected to) as well as for neighboring cells (cells that the mobile can detect but is not connected to).

Depending on the mobile phone (e.g. http://www.gyokovsolutions.com/survey/surveyresults.php) as well as on the connection technology (3G, 4G, etc.), more or less information is retrieved with `getAllCellInfo()`. E.g. some phones do not report information about neighboring cells at all, while other might only report the strength of the signal, etc.

From a `CellInfo` object, one can retrieve the identity of the cell via `getCellIdentity()` (to be precise, it's `getCellIdentityLte()`, `getCellIdentityGsm()` etc. in dependence of the used network technology).

The `CellIdentityLte` object contains (or at least should contain) the values `mcc`, `mnc` and `ci` (cell-identity), which can be used to identify a cell globally (computing the ecgi).

Now, the problem I am facing is that every phone that I have encountered so far (e.g. OnePlus-Three, Samsung S7) is unable to report the cell-identity of the neighboring cells (instead `UNAVAILABLE` (=2147483647) is returned). Other values are available, e.g. the field `PCI` of the `LTECellIdendity` of the neighboring cells were available.

My question is: Has anyone encountered mobile phones which are able to report the `cell-identity` of neighboring cells in a `4G`-network?

This seems to be a recurring problem (the linked discussions concern other technologies, but face the same problem):

- https://github.com/mozilla/ichnaea/issues/17
- [cellID and LAC / PSC for 3G neighboring cells in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701777/cellid-and-lac-psc-for-3g-neighboring-cells-in-android)

Comment: Did you find any suitable phones or make progress on this? I can confirm that the pixel 2 and the Nexus 6 do not report any cell information when calling 'allCellInfo'

Comment: Also - Changing the network type in pixel2 settings (LTE->3G->2G) results in more information being returns about the WCDMA & GSM networks (e.g. MMC/MCC).